how to configure custom error for Media Items can return illegal path
We are working on a Sitecore 10.3 headless implementation. In one scenario, we are encountering server errors (HTTP 500) during media requests. Since this is a headless implementation, all media requests are directed to Sitecore directly.
To address this issue, we attempted to implement custom error handling in our Sitecore solution:
We created a static HTML page for the 500 error.
Updated the Sitecore configuration to use this static HTML page for handling 500 errors. However, this approach does not seem to be working as expected. The server still responds with the default error, and the custom error page is not being displayed.
What is the best way to manage and display a custom error page for 500 errors specifically for media requests in Sitecore?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

You need to deal with images in a slightly different way in Sitecore.
Try adding a custom media handler, then add a try/catch to work out what is causing your 500 error. Then deal with it accordingly.
Something like this should get you started:
public class MediaHandler : Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaRequestHandler
{
    public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        MediaRequest mediaRequest = MediaManager.ParseMediaRequest(context.Request);
        if (mediaRequest != null)
        {
            var media = MediaManager.GetMedia(mediaRequest.MediaUri);
            if (media == null)
            {
                Item mediaItem = null;
                var db = Context.Database;
                var site = Sitecore.Context.Site;
                mediaItem = db.GetItem(context.Request.FilePath);

                // Add try / catch and find out why you are getting 500 error then deal with it
                
            }
        }
        base.ProcessRequest(context);
    }
}

Then add it to your web.config in system.webServer/handlers:
<add verb="*" path="sitecore_media.ashx" type="your-assembly-name.MediaHandler, your-assembly-" name="Sitecore.MediaRequestHandler" />

